# How do I check if zephyr-rtos is present with a preprocessor directive?

Tags: cmake, zephyr-rtos

I need to port some legacy code to zephyr-rtos. I'm using the _*GNUC*_ preprocessor directive to switch some code.

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
    // do new code
#else
    // do legacy code
#endif
```

I would need another preprocessor directive that is more specific to zephyr.

```
#ifdef ZEPHYR_RTOS // ??
```

I would expect zephyr to provides a CMake definition. I tried ZEPHYR_BASE, which is used inside zephyr/CMakeLists.txt, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Zephyr build system defines [`__ZEPHYR__`](https://github.com/zephyrproject-rtos/zephyr/blob/d79cf205c6f64ffcf92c24ea401d29f8b5b5c9b4/CMakeLists.txt#L148), which you can use in your code.